Is it possible to append more tags in a AWS Cloudformation template that uses pre-defined tags?
I have a cloudformation template for creating a security group as follows. It references tags.yaml that contains pre-defined tags in a s3 bucket.
Resources:
  EC2SecurityGroup:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
    DeletionPolicy: Delete
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Test Security Group.
      GroupName: !Ref SecurityGroupName
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - Description: Direct traffic to all destinations.
          CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"
          IpProtocol: -1
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - Description: Sec. group of LB.
          FromPort: 80
          IpProtocol: tcp
          SourceSecurityGroupId: sg-xxxxxxxx
          ToPort: 80
      VpcId: !Ref VPCId
      "Fn::Transform":
        Name: AWS::Include
        Parameters:
          Location: "s3://{bucket-name}/tags.yaml"

I want to now append/add additional tags in this template. Is that possible? I tried adding Tags property but that didnt work. Example:
      "Fn::Transform":
        Name: AWS::Include
        Parameters:
          Location: "s3://{bucket-name}/tags.yaml"
      Tags:
        - Key: TestName
          Value: DummyVal


Worked around it by using nested stack concept. Example:
Resources:
  VPCStack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: !Sub ${S3BucketUrl}/vpc.yaml
      Parameters:
        EnvironmentName: demo-env
      "Fn::Transform":
        Name: AWS::Include
        Parameters:
          Location: !Sub "s3://${S3BucketName}/tags.yaml"

vpc.yaml can now have additional tags:
VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref VpcCIDR
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      InstanceTenancy: default
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName}-vpc

